# How to pass filename to Paypal as value and retrieve the name on success page

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Is there any way to pass a filename as value to paypal and retrieve the name on success page? I am stuck here.I can successfully retrieve all other fields. Any suggestions for the file please.

**Form**

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

**Success.php**

```
$file=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$que=mysqli_query($con,"insert into orders(custom_file,date,customerid,status,ship_days) values('$file',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'$user_id','confirmed','$ships')");
if($que)
{
$m=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['name'],'./ServerUploadedFiles/'.$user.$file);
}
```

Comment: Use custom field option..

Comment: @amit i have already used custom field option for `ship_days`. can i use this for two?

Comment: No... Concatenate the string in custom field by using delimiter

Comment: I don't think that'll work: a customer would upload the file to paypal and paypal's callback would have to upload the file to your server (and I don't think they support either). Or, if you just send the filename, by the time the customer is redirected to your site, the `$_FILES` is no longer set because there is no file upload. And PHP will have likely removed the uploaded file. Better `move_uploaded_file` first, store the filename in the session, redirect to paypal, and on success insert the order.

Comment: @Kenney so you are saying i shouldnot pass filename to paypal variable and retrieve it. But i just save the filename in a session and retrieve it on `success.php`? But then how can i move the file to folder?

Comment: @amit can you guide me with some sample code?

Comment: for example: post custom field value as ship_days&filename.jpg
and on response use explode function to differentiate ship_days and filename

Comment: @amit and how can i move the file to the folder?

Comment: @tabia If you want to move an uploaded file use the move_uploaded_file